# Distributed session reset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis, azure

- Our site is an ASP.NET MVC site, hosted on Azure and using Azure cache service as session provider. Below is our sessionstate configuration:
  [image]
  The cache in Azure is configured to use sliding expiration, with expiration period of 2 hours
  [image]
- Recently we have an issue of users suddenly being kicked out of the website. There is no exception during that time, except for SecurityException which we throw if user's not logged in. It seems that suddenly user's session is lost and ASP.NET assigns them a new session
- As far as we know, since the site is using distributed session state provider, even if the server application pool is recycled, it should not kick out the user/cause session lost
- May I know what are the possible causes for this issue? Is it due to distributed cache session provider or due to IIS or due to our site? How should we debug this issue?
- Below is our production server IIS application pool setting
  [image]

Thank you very much

---